# How do I get this Highlighted feature through webpage code? And what is it called?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is image, and i'm looking for the feature of if i select the icon, it becomes highlighted from BLUE to White.

I'm not sure what this feature is called I tried looking through boostrap and CSS HTML but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. 
 Thank you !

[image: highlight]

Comment: That "feature" is called setting `active` class to vertical tabs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stacked Tabs for that:

```css
/* custom inclusion of right, left and below tabs */

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  border-color: transparent #ddd #ddd #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
  *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 19px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  *border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h3>Tabs -left</h3>

<!-- tabs left -->
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /tabs -->
```

Comment: Ahh lovely ! Thanks so much